# Does employer pay you for the day if you leave for the day due to not being paid on time?

Tags: payroll

Long story short this has been the 3rd time where I was not paid on time within the two years ive been working for this IT company. In the past i had to wait an entire week before i received my paycheck and other times it was a day or two after my initial pay day. No one else has been having this issue within my department only myself has. My employer states its payroll who has been making mistakes. Considering I was not paid Thursday I didnt come into work on friday as i had no gas money to even get to work. Should my employer pay me for that day since it was on their mistake for not paying me on time? What should i do about this going forward as I was finally paid for my hours but no explanation as to why this even occurred. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the wrong question. A company that has repeatedly not paid on time is not a good company to be working for. The company is at high risk of going under and you might not get paid at all. It is time to start looking for a different job.

Comment: "I didn't come into work on Friday as I had no gas money" Are you literally getting paid in cash and then spending it immediately? Did you have literally no money left over from your previous pay? Do you not have a credit card? Or a savings account?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on where you are. In my (European) country, you have to inform your employer that the money is missing and give them at least 14 days of grace period. If the money doesn't arrive until that point, you can formally quit. But if you don't formally quit and just don't show up to work, it will be considered as the fault of the employee (absence without valid excuse) and the employee will not get paid. The situation is probably very different in US at-will states.

Comment: Should your company have paid you on time?  Absolutely!  Should you have failed to show up after not getting paid on time?  Absolutely NOT!  If you actually had a problem where you didn't have the funds to make it to work (very hard for me to believe this part of your story!) you should have called your manager/supervisor and explained the situation as to why you were not going to be able to make it to work.

Comment: I recommend you try to save up a bit of a buffer so that a single late payment does not not cause a cascading effect of problems for you.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, companies must pay you for hours worked.  I know of no requirement to pay you for days missed due to errors of the company.

Some states may have specific requirements for how often you should be paid (New York requires weekly for manual workers I believe).  So the state in question may have laws or regulations regarding penalties or requirements around late paychecks.